# Downloading source code from sourceforge, svn repository empty

Tags: svn, sourceforge

There's a 32bit VST on sourceforge unfortunately I need to recompile it in 64bit for it to work with my DAW.
The SVN repository is not available anymore but the source code is visible from sourceforge, is there any way to download all the files ?

Here is the link: https://sourceforge.net/p/ms812proxy/code/HEAD/tree/

Answer (score 1):

> The SVN repository is not available anymore but the source code is visible from sourceforge

This statement looks incorrect. The link you've shared belongs to an online SVN viewer so data is definitively there and there doesn't seem to be any problem with remote access, as you can verify with any client software:

```
PS C:\tmp\foo\> svn log https://svn.code.sf.net/p/ms812proxy/code/
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r2 | copperphil | 2012-01-16 05:28:31 +0100 (lu., 16 ene. 2012) | 1 line


------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1 | allura | 2012-01-16 04:54:30 +0100 (lu., 16 ene. 2012) | 1 line

Initial commit
------------------------------------------------------------------------
PS C:\tmp\foo> svn checkout https://svn.code.sf.net/p/ms812proxy/code/trunk ms812proxy-code
Checked out revision 2.
```

[image: Repository Browser]

It any case, it's clear that they are either hosting the project development elsewhere or not using version control at all because:

- They created the standard trunk/branches/tags structure and then ignored it.
- There's only one actual commit ever.

Comment: I ended up writing a scripting parsing the links for the only commit and re-creating the folder structure. unfortunately project is from 2013 and has 316 compilation and requires hard to find not distributed anymore sdk so I think that's it.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the data you've industriously parsed from the web site is exactly the same available in HEAD revision with regular `svn co`. If the repo ever had 316 revisions, they're gone from the site as well.

Comment: tbh i have no idea how to get those file i tried to clone the project using tortoise https but ended up with an empty folder, anyway thanks for your answers, in the end i now have the files but it's unbuidable due to a load of errors. When I said 316 compilation i forgot the word error just after. It's 316 compilation error when trying to build it :(

Comment: Please read my answer again, I've even shared the exact commands. If that isn't working for you, you must have some other problem (network connectivity, misconfigured proxy, security software...).